# Synchronized Access of Static Map Object

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, synchronization

I am using a static map object in the web service which will be used in a multithreaded environment.

```
private static Map<String, String> map;
```

The map keeps the record from the database in key-value pair. Since, the database was huge and performing read operation for every request would be a costly affair. I have read the complete database in a map object during service startup and since the same records are supposed to be shared by all the objects, I have declared it as static.

```
static
{
      map = loadDatabase();
}

private Map<String,String> loadDatabase()
{   
    //database operations
    Map<String,String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String,String>(new LengthBasedComparator());
    //put all records in a map in the length sorted manner
    return sortedmap            
}
```

I have used a `TreeMap` because I wanted it to be sorted based on the length of the key. Which is done using `LenghBasedComparator` class

Had it been read operations only, it would have worked fine.

```
public String getStringMatch(String key)
{
   // additional processing
   map.get(key);
   // more processing
}
```

Now, a new requirement comes up to update the in-memory database i.e. the map.

```
public String updateInMemoryDatabase(String key, String value)
{
    //....
    synchronized(map)
    {
       map.put(key,value);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
   //......
}
```

I have placed the `put` operation on the map in `synchronized` block.

Is this the correct way to do synchronized access to the map?

Or,

1. Does making the map volatile serve the purpose?
2. Since I need the map in the sorted manner I can't use ConcurrentHashMap. As, it may change the ordering. Is there any way to use it?

Please give some pointers in this regard.

Thanks

Nishit

Comment: "the database was huge...I have read the complete database in a map object"  I know "huge" is a subjective term, but if it fits in memory, can you really call it huge?

Comment: Synchronizing the put() is not enough.  You have to synchronize all of the get()s too.  Otherwise, one thread could do an unsynchronized get() while another thread was in the middle of a synchronized put(), and the first thread could possibly see the Map in an invalid state, and therefore get a bad result or even crash the program.

Comment: No, `volatile` won't help.  It would not prevent two threads from accessing the map at the same time, and in this case, it might not do anything at all because no thread ever writes the `map` variable after the first assignment.  NOTE: There is no such thing as a volatile _object_.  If you write `volatile Map<...> map;` that's a property of the _variable_.  It doesn't change anything about the Map object to which the variable refers.

Comment: Be careful with the use of a custom comparator in your TreeMap. If your comparator is truly only comparing on length, then the actual value of the string does not matter. At that point you might as well have a map just keyed by Integer (length of the string).

Comment: Side note:  You should not use return values to indicate error conditions (like `return SUCCESS`).  That's what C programs did.  The method's return type should be void, and it should throw an exception upon failure.  Returning at all would then imply success.  This way, you don't need to rely on callers who invariably forget to check the return value.

Comment: @james got your point :). But with "huge" I meant to say that the database is big enough to load for each request and doing that will take too much time to complete the request.   Thanks for your pointers on "synchronize" and "volatile".

Comment: @Brett Can you put some more light on it? Does it mean that, If I use custom length based comparator then I will have a map keyed by integer which is supposed to be keyed by the string?

Comment: @NishitJain if the comparator says 2 values are equal (i.e. the length is the same), then the map will treat the 2 keys as equal. If that is not the desired behavior, you need to handle the case where the length is the same by providing another comparator. You could revert to the natural comparing of `String` as a secondary sort. In java 8: `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ConcurrentHashMap if you need the keys sorted, but you can use [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html), and it's likely better than trying to handle all the concurrency yourself.